# Fast way to intersect a list generated via a for loop from a dataframe with dictionary values using Single Pass algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dataframe

I am trying to implement the `Single Pass` algorithm to the following problem:

- for each index in the dataframe, identify which columns contain that value
- these columns' names are then stored as a list
- there's a dictionary where the key is a column name in the dataframe and the value is all the other column names in the dataframe
- for each key in that dictionary, intersect its value with the list generated from step 2) above
- update the value of that dictionary key with the result of intersection

Please see my code below

```
def sp_algorithm(self, dataframe, col_dict):

    # for each cursor value, get all columns that has it
    for ind, i in zip(dataframe.index, range(0, len(dataframe.index))):

        # vectorised index operation
        cols_list = dataframe.columns[dataframe.isin([ind]).any()]

        # for each column in col_dict.keys(), intersect its values with cols_list to get the remaining
        # if the current column value is null, then do nothing
        for key_col in col_dict.keys():

            column_val = dataframe.loc[ind, key_col]

            if (column_val == column_val) & (column_val != ''):
                col_dict[key_col] = list(set(col_dict[key_col]).intersection(cols_list))
```

The dictionary containing column names look like this:

```
col_dict = {'col_A': ['col_B', 'col_C'], 'col_B' = ['col_A', 'col_C'], 'col_C': ['col_A', 'col_B']}
```

As you can see, my code is currently of `O(n^2)` time complexity as there are 2 `for loop`s in there.

Currently, each iteration (including the 2 x `for loop`s) takes around 0.8 seconds, which is probably not a problem for a small dataset. However, the dataset I am processing is of **300k** rows and over **80** columns.

My problem is: how do I implement single pass to the dictionary intersection step so there's only going to be 1 for loop instead of 2?

**EDIT**
The dataframe will contain **sorted** index and values in **ascending** order as below:

```
        col_A col_B col_C
index
0        nan     0     0
1          1     nan   1
2          2     nan   2
3        nan     3     3
```

So, my current function would loop through for each `index`, `ind` to get the col names `cols_list = dataframe.columns[dataframe.isin([ind]).any()]` and intersect these with the dictionary values.

**1st iteration:**
`cols_list = ['col_B', 'col_C']`
then, it will look up the values for each key in the `col_dict` (only if the column has a value, so for `nan` it will be skipped) and intersect it and update it.

`col_dict = {'col_A': ['col_B', 'col_C'], 'col_B' = ['col_C'], 'col_C': ['col_B']}`

**2nd iteration:**
`col_B` is skipped when checking dictionary value as it's `nan` and it's dictionary value stays the same
`cols_list = ['col_A', 'col_C']`
`col_dict = {'col_A': ['col_C'], 'col_B' = ['col_C'], 'col_C': []}`

**3rd iteration:**
`col_B` is skipped when checking dictionary value as it's `nan` and it's dictionary value stays the same
`cols_list = ['col_A', 'col_C']`
`col_dict = {'col_A': ['col_C'], 'col_B' = ['col_C'], 'col_C': []}`

**4th iteration:**
`col_A` is skipped when checking dictionary value as it's `nan` and it's dictionary value stays the same
`cols_list = ['col_B', 'col_C']`
`col_dict = {'col_A': ['col_C'], 'col_B' = ['col_C'], 'col_C': []}`

Answer (score 1):

The strength of numpy/scipy/pandas lies in using C code to do most of the work for you. Given that, in your words, there are 300k rows and 80 columns, I suggest that you first make every effort to ensure that you are processing the rows in C, not python. Thus, your first loop should be eliminated: don't process 300k elements using python.

The way I read your requirements, you have an index (row labels) that has values of some type that may appear in the individual cells in your other columns. Something like this:

```
Index   A  B  C  D
  1     0  0  3  0
  2     2  0  1  -1
  3     0  0  0  0
  192   0  0  1  -1
```

You want to know, for each Index, if that value appears in any of column A, column B, column C, etc. If *any* Index value appears in a column, that column is "ALIVE".

At the end of the process, columns are either ALIVE or not, and you then want to filter your other dictionary to exclude columns that are not ALIVE.

In my example above, column A is considered ALIVE because of { 2 }, and column C is considered ALIVE because of { 3, 1 }, but columns B and D are not ALIVE because they don't contain any values that are present in Index. Is this right?

Try using `isin` to determine if the values in the columns are present in the index. Then use `any` to collapse the boolean results to a single boolean value that determines if the column is alive:

```
row_labels = df.index
col_is_alive = df.isin(row_labels).any()  # NB: any(index=0) is default
```

(NOTE: I am not in a place where I can run this code. It may contain syntax or other errors.)

Now you have a series of 80 boolean values, telling you which columns are alive. You can do your processing however you like.

```
alive_col_names = { name for name in df.columns if col_is_alive[name] }  # Set comprehension
```

However, your initial problem statement makes it sound like you are doing this one time (as opposed to iteratively updating the groups of column names). In that case, rather than intersect the dictionary values (lists of every column name but the key) I would suggest simply computing the values directly. That is, compute the key->value pairs directly rather than trying to "intersect" the value lists with that list of all column names.

```
col_dict = { key:alive_col_names - {key} for key in alive_col_names}
```

On the other hand, if you are somehow iteratively updating these values, then I would suggest you make your second data structure a dictionary of string -> set instead of string -> list, since that will give you access to the standard set operations and behavior.

```
new_col_dict = {}

for key, other_cols in col_dict.items():
    if key not in alive_col_names:
        continue

    new_col_dict[key] = other_cols.interset(alive_col_names)

col_dict = new_col_dict
```

(Which can be collapsed using a dict comprehension but perhaps should not be, in the interest of readability.)

Comment: apologies that I didn't include the details of the dataframe. please see the question edit I made just now. so, i actually iterate through the updating dictionary step for each index value which is why it's a `O(n^2)` time complexity